# Print JSON attributes whose key and value are different

Tags: json, key, jq

I have a very long JSON file with the following structure (there are no nested attributes):

```
{
    "Aaa aaa aaa": "Aaa aaa aaa",
    "Bbb bbb bbb": "Bbb bbb bbb",
    "Ccc ccc ccc": "Xxx xxx xxx",
    "Ddd ddd ddd": "Ddd ddd ddd",
    "Eee eee eee": "Yyy yyy yyy"
}
```

And I need to print those pairs whose key does not match the value. In this example, I'm expecting this kind of result:

```
    "Ccc ccc ccc": "Xxx xxx xxx",
    "Eee eee eee": "Yyy yyy yyy"
```

I know how to capture and print keys and values with **sed**...

```
sed -n "s/^\t\"\(.*\)\": \"\(.*\)\",\?$/\1 \2/p" file.json
```

...but I do not know how to make the comparison between both groups. Maybe **sed** is not the right tool for this task and I should be using **awk** or **jq** instead, however in don't have any experience with the latter.

Therefore, which would be the right way or tool to search differences in name-value pairs within a JSON file?

Comment: `which would be the right way or tool to search differences in name-value pairs within a JSON file?` `jq` is the tool to do anything with a JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `jq` you can use the `with_entries()` function. It puts the keys and values of each record in the object into named variables `.key` and `.value` and you basically have to evaluate if they are *not* the same.

```
jq 'with_entries(select(.key != .value))'
```

See [with_entries(..)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) from the manual to know more

---

Follow-up question to do a case insensitive comparison. Can be done by converting both key/value to a particular case

```
with_entries(select( (.key| ascii_downcase) != (.value| ascii_downcase)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it worked like a charm! Also I don't know if this should be a different question but, is it possible to make the comparison case insensitive?

Comment: @Serchu: See update. If that doesn't solve your problem, post an alternate input and output expected representing your problem

Comment: Your updated answer solves my problem perfectly, that's exactly what I needed. I had never used jq before, so I really appreciate that you bailed me out so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/\(\".*\"\): \1/d' file.json
```

Or if you also want to eliminate the braces:

```
sed '/\"/!d;/\(\".*\"\): \1/d' file.json
```

Comment: That's very nice, I had no idea you could use capture groups also on that side of the regex, thanks for your answer!